# Displaying two curves in R3 in such a way that the foreground and background are clear

Tags: plot, 3d

I apologize for the elementary question - I am a newbie with Python. I am trying to display two interlaced circles in R3 but python doesn't properly show who is "in front". What I want is Python to give what Mathematica gives, as in this figure:
[Mathematica figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UeMX.png)
instead of
[Python figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcOOb.png)
The Python code I used is below, and it needs to be adjusted (no worry about viewing angle - I can take care of that later).
Many thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Define the parametric equations for the circles
def circle_xy(t, h, k, r):
    x = h + r * np.cos(t)
    y = k + r * np.sin(t)
    z = 0 * np.ones_like(t)
    return x, y, z

def circle_yz(t, h, k, r):
    x = h + r * np.sin(t)
    y = 0 * np.ones_like(t)
    z = k + r * np.cos(t)
    return x, y, z

t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)

# Plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x1, y1, z1 = circle_xy(t, 0, 0, 1)
x2, y2, z2 = circle_yz(t, 1, 0, 1)

ax.plot(x1, y1, z1, label='unit circle centered at x=0, y=0 in the plane z=0',linewidth=3)
ax.plot(x2, y2, z2, label='unit circle centered at x=1, z=0 in the plane y=0',linewidth=3)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.legend()

ax.view_init(30, 120)

plt.show()
```

I tried the code shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Plotly is great with this, it makes it easier to inspect surfaces in R3 in a way that would be more difficult in matplotlib (allows for panning, rotating, and zooming all in the HTML output)

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Define the parametric equations for the circles
def circle_xy(t, h, k, r):
    x = h + r * np.cos(t)
    y = k + r * np.sin(t)
    z = 0 * np.ones_like(t)
    return x, y, z

def circle_yz(t, h, k, r):
    x = h + r * np.sin(t)
    y = 0 * np.ones_like(t)
    z = k + r * np.cos(t)
    return x, y, z

t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)

x1, y1, z1 = circle_xy(t, 0, 0, 1)
x2, y2, z2 = circle_yz(t, 1, 0, 1)

# Create the 3D plot in plotly
fig = go.Figure()

# Add circles to the plot
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x1, y=y1, z=z1, mode='lines', name='unit circle centered at x=0, y=0 in the plane z=0', line=dict(width=3)))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x2, y=y2, z=z2, mode='lines', name='unit circle centered at x=1, z=0 in the plane y=0', line=dict(width=3)))

# Setting the axis labels
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(xaxis_title='X', yaxis_title='Y', zaxis_title='Z'))

# Display the
```

plot
fig.show()